# Is the current on a motor's nameplate its no-load current, full load current, or locked rotor current?

Tags: motor

Say a motor has 1.49A on its nameplate. Is this its full-load current, no-load current or something else?

Comment: Don't lock the motor!!!!    $$$$ Is there an RPM specified also?  The values listed would be at that RPM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect the nameplate to give the rated load current at rated voltage.

The no-load current may be as low as 10 to 20% of this and the locked rotor more than 500% of this rating. That you can verify using a DMM ohm meter on the coils to compute this current and report back in your question based on V/DCR.

The results also depend on the type of motor and winding configuration for the torque profile in an induction motor. Some have more excitation current to flatten the torque curve.